# page is giving error when previewing with page template designed for XSLT TBB

Tags: tridion

I am working on an XSLT TBB in Tridion 2011 SP1, using the XSLT Mediator from SDL Tridion World. I have created an XSLT TBB, Component Template and Page Template and a Page for it. But the Page Template that I have created is giving the following error when i am trying to preview the page:

> XmlResponder failed render request :

```xml
<tcmapi:Message version="6.0" from="Anguilla" xmlns:tcmapi="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0/TCMAPI">
    <tcmapi:Response ID="acc265b4-d01f-4dec-8d8e-0b4fc1039160" success="false" xmlns:tcmapi="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0/TCMAPI">
        <tcmapi:Error>
            <tcm:Error ErrorCode="80040000" Category="18" Source="Kernel" Severity="1" xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">
                <tcm:Line ErrorCode="80040000" Cause="false" MessageID="16138"><![CDATA[Unable to get rendered content of Page (tcm:9-511-64).]]></tcm:Line>
                <tcm:Line ErrorCode="80040000" Cause="true"><![CDATA[Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]]></tcm:Line>
                <tcm:Details>
                    <tcm:CallStack>
                        <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.TcdlParser.Process(Item,TagHandler)</tcm:Location>
                        <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Templates.EnableSiteEdit.Transform(Engine,Package)</tcm:Location>
                        <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly.AssemblyMediator.Transform(Engine,Template,Package)</tcm:Location>
                        <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly.CSharpSourceCodeMediator.RunTemplate(Engine,Package,String,String)</tcm:Location>
                        <tcm:Location>Tridion.Templating.CSharpTemplate.CSharpSourceTemplate.Transform(Engine,Package)</tcm:Location>
                        <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly.CSharpSourceCodeMediator.Transform(Engine,Template,Package)</tcm:Location>
                        <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.ExecuteTemplate(Template,Package)</tcm:Location>
                        <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.InvokeTemplate(Package,TemplateInvocation,Template)</tcm:Location>
                        <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Compound.CompoundTemplateMediator.Transform(Engine,Template,Package)</tcm:Location>
                        <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.ExecuteTemplate(Template,Package)</tcm:Location>
                        <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.InvokeTemplate(Package,TemplateInvocation,Template)</tcm:Location>
                        <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.TransformPackage(Template,Package)</tcm:Location>
                        <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.TemplatingRenderer.Render(ResolvedItem,PublishInstruction,PublicationTarget,RenderedItem,RenderContext)</tcm:Location>
                        <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Rendering.RenderEngine.Render(ResolvedItem,PublishInstruction,PublicationTarget,RenderContext)</tcm:Location>
                        <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Rendering.RenderEngine.Render(IdentifiableObject,Template,PublishInstruction,PublicationTarget,RenderContext)</tcm:Location>
                        <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Rendering.ComWrapper.RenderEngineFacade.RenderItemWithTemplate(IdentifiableObject,Template,PublishInstruction,PublicationTarget,RenderContext)</tcm:Location>
                        <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Rendering.ComWrapper.RenderEngineFacade.RenderItemWithTemplate(IdentifiableObject,Template,String)</tcm:Location>
                        <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Rendering.ComWrapper.RenderEngineFacade.RenderPage(UserContext,String,String,String)</tcm:Location>
                        <tcm:Location>UtilitiesPublish.RenderPage</tcm:Location>
                        <tcm:Location>Page.Render</tcm:Location>
                        <tcm:Location>Request.Render</tcm:Location>
                    </tcm:CallStack>
                </tcm:Details>
            </tcm:Error>
        </tcmapi:Error>
    </tcmapi:Response>
</tcmapi:Message>
```

The Page Template DWT I have created looks like this:

```xml
<html>
<body>
<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="Components" -->
    @@RenderComponentPresentation()@@
<!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
</body>
</html>
```

I have enabled "Enable SiteEdit 2009" and "Default Finish Actions" in Page Template. My Compound Component Template is set to generate an XML fragment as its output type.

Comment: It is a little hard to debug this without more information. Please answer the following:
1) What version of Tridion are you using?
2) Are you using Compound Component Templates
3) You mention a XSLT TBB, are you using the XSLT Mediator from SDLTridionWorld.com
4) Are you able to preview the output of just the ComponentPresentation without the page?

Comment: 1.I am using sdl tridion 2011 sp1
2.Yes i am using Compound component templates
3.I am using XSLT mediator from SDL TridionWorld.com
4.I am able to preview the component presenetation without the page.

Comment: Can you run your template in Template Builder and check at what template exactly an error occurs?

Comment: the problem has been verified..some problem in TBB.

Comment: Does this mean you solved the problem, or just validated the error is in your XSLT TBB? If it is solved, please up vote any comments that helped you.

Comment: @Chris Summers.. how to vote for the comment

Comment: As your page template uses DWT syntax, I assume that your XSLT template is the component template. What happens when you preview that? Also - what happens when you publish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the issue with the TBB was a bad setting in the CME view of the template building block (TBB), which needs to use the XSLT type, not C# fragment or assembly (I'm guessing from the namespace below).

I don't see the XSLT Mediator Namespace in the stack trace (update this if that's a bad assumption).

> Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.TcdlParser.Process(Item,TagHandler) 
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Templates.EnableSiteEdit.Transform(Engine,Package)
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly.AssemblyMediator.Transform(Engine,Template,Package)
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly.**CSharpSourceCodeMediator**.RunTemplate(Engine,Package,String,String) Tridion.Templating.CSharpTemplate.**CSharpSourceTemplate**.Transform(Engine,Package)
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly.**CSharpSourceCodeMediator**.Transform(Engine,Template,Package)

The [instructions are pretty thorough](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/extension_overview/xsltmediator.aspx) in case anyone else has an issue.